# How to retrieve a value from table

Tags: html, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I am displaying a table values by using jsp in that i hv JDBC code to display the table data.
pls see the code below.

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <th>USN</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Semister</th>
            <th>Mobile No.</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
<!-- all you need with Tablecloth is a regular, well formed table. No need for id's, class names... --> 
<%
     PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("select * from sttable");
 ResultSet es = s.executeQuery();
 while(es.next())
 {


     %>


        <tr>
            <td><%=es.getString(2) %></td>
            <td><%=es.getString(1) %></td>
            <td><%=es.getString(3) %></td>
            <td><%=es.getString(4) %></td>
            <td><%=es.getString(5) %></td>
            </tr>

      <%} %>
            </table>
```

The above code displays values in the table ,what i want to do is select a particular value 
by a giving a link to it as show below.

```
        <td><a href="#"<%=es.getString(2) %></a></td>
```

by clicking particular value i want to retrive that value details from the table 
for Eg.USN is the primary key and by clicking on it i want to get the data associated with that USN,Help me out in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `es.getString(0)` is the location of the primary key. You can do something like:

```
<tr>
    <% if(myCondition == true) { %>
        <td><a href="loadDetails.jsp?id=<%=es.getString(0)%>"><%=es.getString(2)%></a></td>
    <% } else { %>
        <td><%=es.getString(2) %></td>
    <% } %>
    <td><%=es.getString(1) %></td>
    <td><%=es.getString(3) %></td>
    <td><%=es.getString(4) %></td>
    <td><%=es.getString(5) %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: but how to get that id value in loadDetails.
jsp

Comment: i hv tried the above code,but its giving only last value FROM the table